# Can I set a custom class as the default base class for my controllers in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, default, code-structure

I'd like to inherit all my controllers from a custom base class that I write myself. I can change the line every time I add a new controller, but it would be nicer if I could somewhere specify the default value that gets set there. That way I wouldn't need to worry about forgetting this, and other people who get added to the project later on would have an easier time.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This is not about MVC IMHO - what you're talking about is defining, somehow, a default base class for a group of classes. And sorry, this could be done in dynamic languages like Python and Ruby, but it cannot be really done in C#... Of course, you probably could *emulate* such behavior, maybe using DI or reflection. Or using some scope resolution trick like Rob West did.

Comment: @rsenna while it cannot be done at the language/compiler level, ASP.NET MVC offers customizable tooling options that makes this possible. Read my response to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the T4 template that gets used when the Add Controller action gets invoked. Basically you would have to copy the template from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 3\CodeTemplates\AddController\Controller.tt` to '~\CodeTemplates\AddController\Controller.tt` in your project file.

More info available [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/01/27/asp-net-mvc-1-0-release-candidate-now-available.aspx) (scroll down to "Adding and Customizing Scaffold Templates")

Comment: This would then be applied across all MVC solutions which would surely not be a good thing!

Comment: Well, if you copy the `Controller.tt` file to your project it will only apply to that single project. Or you could modify the file in its original location, but then every developer working on the project would have to modify their machine's files. Copying the template file into the project (while sometimes repetitive) is currently the best way to achieve this while supporting multiple developers, source control, etc.

Comment: Woo hoo! It worked! Beautiful! This templating feature is just what I was missing in the old VS2008!

Comment: Actually the same technique is available in VS 2008 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yup that's an easy task to do. First create a class called "BaseController" for example which inherits from Controller. Then all your controllers would inherit from BaseController.

EDIT: I *think* that using a T4 template to generate your costume controller (called BaseController or maybe Controller - whichever you prefer) would also work. I've seen Scot Hanselman do something similar in one of his talks.

Comment: ah I see, now that I read your answer I understood the question better. My solution works fine, but I'm not sure Vilx would want to implement my solution or yours. But to be honest, I usually try to stay away from naming my classes similarly to those in the .NET framework (or ASP.NET MVC in this case) itself, that creates a lot of confusion, and even Visual Studio complains about it. (Note: I've just edited my post)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using namespaces: create a class called Controller in the same namespace as your controllers, e.g.:

```
namespace UI.Controllers
{
    public class Controller : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
    {
        //Code here
    }
}
```

and then the standard unqualified references to Controller will reference your base class instead of the System.Web.Mvc.Controller one.

Might get confusing though - I'd rather just have to remember to reference the base class.

Comment: Indeed, I too prefer to give names to my classes which are not in conflict with framework classes.